# How to debug Typescript code with Thunderbird?

Tags: node.js, typescript, thunderbird, web-ext

I am wondering, is it possible to debug node.js/Typescript application (addon) for Thunderbird. Do you have any experience about that?

I was trying to use web-ext. But it fails. I can't find any info about using it with Thunderbird.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.